# WSO2 Message Broker JNDI usage

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use Message Broker but i have some questions.

1 I have created a queue on message broker and i could add new message to message broker with proxy service on ESB. However when i try to listen this queue on Application Server i could not get queue connection factory on my code. If i follow this blog http://pzf.fremantle.org/2011/04/introduction-to-wso2-message-broker_05.html i could achieve the get message from my queue. But i think i should not create connection to message broker on my code, i should get connection from application server. So i have uncomment to JMSListener attribute and you could see it at the below. If i try to get queue from here with this code

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
initCtx.lookup("myQueueConnectionFactory");
```

i am getting **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name myQueueConnectionFactory is not bound in this Context exception**. Do you have any suggestion to get connection from application server.

```
    <parameter locked="false" name="myTopicConnectionFactory">
        <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">TopicConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">topic</parameter>
    </parameter>


    <parameter locked="false" name="myQueueConnectionFactory">
        <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter locked="false" name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>

    <parameter name="default" locked="false">
        <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial" locked="false">org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url" locked="false">resources/jndi.properties</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName" locked="false">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType" locked="false">queue</parameter>
    </parameter>
```

2 How many times message broker send queue item to subscriber. For example message broker send item to subscriber and somehow subcriber can not accomplished the job. So item is not deleted from message broker queue. When will it try to send this item to subscriber again and how many times it will try to send this item to send subscriber.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

When you are saving the message to the Queue using ESB, you need to specify the ConnectionFactory from your endpoint uri configuration as given below.

```
    <address uri="jms:/myQueueName?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory&amp;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:5672&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue&amp;java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties" statistics="enable"/>
```